# Could you help me calculating the following integral?

Tags: integration

Could you help me calculating the following integral?
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2a^2}}}dx, a>0$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html

Comment: Nice!!!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2a^2}}}dx, a>0 = a\sqrt{2\pi}$

Using the Gaussian integral: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: Great!!! Thank you very much!!!